# CSS - Transition not smooth in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, transition

A simple transition on font-size is resulting in stuttering in safari, where as it's smooth in chrome and firefox. Is this a safari issue, a webkit issue or something else? Any hack is appreciated.

```css
input {
  font-size: 1vw;
  transition: font-size 0.4s;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
input:focus {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello" value="hello"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `transition:duration`

```
transition-duration:0.4s;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
-ms-transition-duration:0.4s;
-moz-transition-duration:0.4s;
```

```css
input {
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  transition-duration:0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
  -ms-transition-duration:0.4s;
  -moz-transition-duration:0.4s;
  visibility:visible !important;
}
input:focus {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello" value="hello" />
```

Comment: Did not make any difference

Comment: did you remove your browser catch

Comment: Beat me to it, looks like it works fine, up vote for that one! :)

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao can you check it now ,i found what is the problem, the older version of safari can't get the viewport height and viewport width

Comment: Don't make changes to the font-size

Comment: `vw` not working with older version of safari, try to update the browser , you can see your code working, i have faced this issue before , then i check with mac engine there is no problem,

Comment: this is not your issue, you are using window safari right ?

Comment: I am running safari 10.0.2 on macOS and the font-size HAS to be in `vw`