# CSS transform transition affecting dynamic title of button in react on state change

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile-safari

I have a custom Button Component in react which on hover transform using scale(value). I am using this button 2 times.

One with only dynamic content without any onClick property e.g

```
<Button className={`${classes.btn} ${classes["main-btn"]}`}>
              {isLoginMode
                ? "Login"
                : isRegisterMode
                ? "Register"
                : "Reset Password"}
            </Button>
```

And then with onClick to change some state e.g

```
<Button
          properties={{
            onClick: () => {
              setAuthMode(
                isLoginMode ? AuthModes.register : AuthModes.login
              );
            },
          }}
          className={`${classes.btn} ${classes["alt-btn"]}`}
        >
          {isLoginMode ? "Register" : "Login"}
        </Button>
```

In desktop it is working fine, but on safari mobile, there is delay in changing text in second button when state change. there is delay because of the transition property because it works well when I remove transition property.

Here is CSS.

In this component:

```
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.7rem 0.9rem;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

In Custom Button Component

```
.btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.8rem 1.2rem;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  border-radius: var(--radius-low);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following answer maybe can help you
[CSS - Transition not smooth in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310569/css-transition-not-smooth-in-safari)

```css
input {
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  transition-duration:0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
  -ms-transition-duration:0.4s;
  -moz-transition-duration:0.4s;
  visibility:visible !important;
}
input:focus {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="hello" value="hello" />
```